# SMARTGWT - SectionStackSection - deleting an Item from the Section possible?

Tags: java, gwt, web, smartgwt

im using SmartGWT 4.
I have an SectionStack with some SectionsStackSections in it.
Now i added some DynamicForms with TextItems, Checkboxes etc. to the a Section.
I also added an delete button for each Dynamic Form
What I want now is, when i click on the delete button the DynamicForm should be deleted
from the Section

but.. I can't find any delete function in a SectionStackSection 
there is a Function for the DynamicForms called "removeFromParent" but it doesn't seem to work..

Does anyone got some ideas? :-)
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMARTGWT - delete DynamicForm from SectionStackSection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327241/smartgwt-delete-dynamicform-from-sectionstacksection)

Comment: @RAS this question is asked before duplicated question as mentioned by you.

Comment: @Braj, IMHO It doesn't matter. The post which contains a meaningful question/answer should be kept.

Comment: @RAS I agree with you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply call below line

```
dynamicForm.getElement().removeFromParent();
```