# SMARTGWT - delete DynamicForm from SectionStackSection

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have the same problem, that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896848/smartgwt-sectionstacksection-deleting-an-item-from-the-section-possible). The problem got missunderstood and I don't have the privileg to comment so I created this question. He wants to delete a DynamicForm out of an SectionStackSection object. my situation is the following: I added some DynamicForm objects to the SectionStackSection by using the setFields(FormItem... fields) method and I also added a Button to delete this FormItem out of the SectionStackSection. The problem's the same. Also Tried DynamicForm.removeFromParent(), but the parent object is null in DynamicForm.

EDIT: That's how my SectionStack is build:

```
SectionStack
  SectionStackSection
     DynamicForm df1 // added via SectionStackSection.addItem(df1)
       Button btn1 // added via DynamicForm.addChild(btn1)
         ClickHandler ch1
       FormItem[] fiList1 // added via DynamicForm.setFields(fiList1)
     DynamicForm df2 // added via SectionStackSection.addItem(df2)
       Button btn2 // added via DynamicForm.addChild(btn2)
         ClickHandler ch2
       FormItem[] fiList2 // added via DynamicForm.setFields(fiList2)
     // ... some more DynamicForm objects added
     DynamicForm dfX
       Button btnX
         ClickHandler chX
       FormItem[] fiListX
  SectionStackSection
    // ...
  // ...
```

By pressing btn1 for example, df1 should be deleted. The SectionStackSection should be stil shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call below line

```
dynamicForm.getElement().removeFromParent();
```

Comment: Won't that delete the SectionStackSection out of the SectionStack?

Comment: What you want to delete? `SectionStackSection` or `DynamicForm` added in `SectionStackSection`. Please confirm.

Comment: @Armin I have also edited my last post at [SMARTGWT - SectionStackSection - deleting an Item from the Section possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896848/smartgwt-sectionstacksection-deleting-an-item-from-the-section-possible?answertab=votes#tab-top). Thanks again Now the problem is clear to me.